# How to generate custom CSV report with test results using Allure?

Tags: java, csv, junit, testng, allure

In our project, we are using TestNG for tests and have Allure in place to generate the test report. We have a requirement where we need to generate a custom CSV report containing the test results in a specific format along with Allure report.

We thought of writing a custom report generator by implementing TestNG's `IReporter` interface to generate the CSV file. That works; however, we would also like to include few Allure specific data, such as `@Title`, `@Description` and `@Step`, also as part of the CSV report.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can collect required meta-data via Allure 2 [listeners](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/tree/master/allure-java-commons/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/listener). But note that it's not enough just to implement corresponding interfaces. You have to follow [SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) guidelines and create required references within `META-INF/services` folder.

Comment: OK. I'll have a look at it. Thank you!